# Creating gif barcode using barcode4j

Tags: java, servlets, barcode, gif

I'm trying to create barcode using `barcode4j` lib. This is what I've got:[image] And it looks smooth. This is how I do:

```
        BitmapCanvasProvider provider = null;


        Interleaved2Of5Bean bean = new Interleaved2Of5Bean();
        int dpi = 100;

        // Configure the barcode generator
        bean.setModuleWidth(UnitConv.in2mm(1.0f /
                                           dpi)); // makes the narrow
        // bar
        // width exactly
        // one
        // pixel

        bean.doQuietZone(false);
        provider =
                new BitmapCanvasProvider(100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY,
                                         true, 0);
        bean.generateBarcode(provider, request.getParameter("barcode"));
        provider.finish();


        BufferedImage barcodeImage = provider.getBufferedImage();
        response.setContentType("image/gif");
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(barcodeImage, "gif", outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
```

How to increase its difinition?

Comment: if you mean resolution, then you should modify the first parameter of `BitmapCanvasProvider` constructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution . This is how I did:

```
    Interleaved2Of5Bean bean = new Interleaved2Of5Bean();

    bean.setHeight(10d);

    bean.doQuietZone(false);

    OutputStream out =
        new java.io.FileOutputStream(new File("output.png"));

    BitmapCanvasProvider provider =
        new BitmapCanvasProvider(out, "image/x-png", 110,
                                 BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, false,
                                 0);
    bean.generateBarcode(provider, request.getParameter("barcode"));

    provider.finish();

    BufferedImage barcodeImage = provider.getBufferedImage();
    response.setContentType("image/x-png");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(barcodeImage, "png", outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found an example in the [jar](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/download.html#Releases) file (in examples directory). I post it here if someone else are looking for it.
Also here is a [list](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/examples.html) of all supported barcode.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2004 Jeremias Maerki.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.code39.Code39Bean;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapCanvasProvider;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.tools.UnitConv;

/**
 * This example demonstrates creating a bitmap barcode using the bean API.
 * 
 * @author Jeremias Maerki
 * @version $Id: SampleBitmapBarcodeWithBean.java,v 1.2 2006/11/07 16:45:28 jmaerki Exp $
 */
public class SampleBitmapBarcodeWithBean {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Create the barcode bean
            Code39Bean bean = new Code39Bean();

            final int dpi = 150;

            //Configure the barcode generator
            bean.setModuleWidth(UnitConv.in2mm(1.0f / dpi)); //makes the narrow bar 
                                                             //width exactly one pixel
            bean.setWideFactor(3);
            bean.doQuietZone(false);

            //Open output file
            File outputFile = new File("out.jpg");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            try {
                //Set up the canvas provider for monochrome JPEG output 
                BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(
                        out, "image/jpeg", dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);

                //Generate the barcode
                bean.generateBarcode(canvas, "123456");

                //Signal end of generation
                canvas.finish();
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a more advanced example that add custom element to the barcode

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Jeremias Maerki
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/* $Id: SampleBarcodeEnhanced.java,v 1.1 2010/10/05 08:56:04 jmaerki Exp $ */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.datamatrix.DataMatrixBean;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.datamatrix.SymbolShapeHint;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapCanvasProvider;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapEncoder;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapEncoderRegistry;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.tools.UnitConv;

/**
 * This class demonstrates how to create a barcode bitmap that is enhanced by custom elements.
 *
 * @version $Id: SampleBarcodeEnhanced.java,v 1.1 2010/10/05 08:56:04 jmaerki Exp $
 */
public class SampleBarcodeEnhanced {

    private void generate(File outputFile) throws IOException {
        String msg = "Sample Message";
        String[] paramArr = new String[] {"Information 1", "Information 2", "Barcode4J is cool!"};

        //Create the barcode bean
        DataMatrixBean bean = new DataMatrixBean();

        final int dpi = 200;

        //Configure the barcode generator
        bean.setModuleWidth(UnitConv.in2mm(8.0f / dpi)); //makes a dot/module exactly eight pixels
        bean.doQuietZone(false);
        bean.setShape(SymbolShapeHint.FORCE_RECTANGLE);

        boolean antiAlias = false;
        int orientation = 0;
        //Set up the canvas provider to create a monochrome bitmap
        BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(
                dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, antiAlias, orientation);

        //Generate the barcode
        bean.generateBarcode(canvas, msg);

        //Signal end of generation
        canvas.finish();

        //Get generated bitmap
        BufferedImage symbol = canvas.getBufferedImage();

        int fontSize = 32; //pixels
        int lineHeight = (int)(fontSize * 1.2);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        int width = symbol.getWidth();
        int height = symbol.getHeight();
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), antiAlias, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < paramArr.length; i++) {
            String line = paramArr[i];
            Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(line, frc);
            width = (int)Math.ceil(Math.max(width, bounds.getWidth()));
            height += lineHeight;
        }

        //Add padding
        int padding = 2;
        width += 2 * padding;
        height += 3 * padding;

        BufferedImage bitmap = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)bitmap.getGraphics();
        g2d.setBackground(Color.white);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        g2d.setFont(font);

        //Place the barcode symbol
        AffineTransform symbolPlacement = new AffineTransform();
        symbolPlacement.translate(padding, padding);
        g2d.drawRenderedImage(symbol, symbolPlacement);

        //Add text lines (or anything else you might want to add)
        int y = padding + symbol.getHeight() + padding;
        for (int i = 0; i < paramArr.length; i++) {
            String line = paramArr[i];
            y += lineHeight;
            g2d.drawString(line, padding, y);
        }
        g2d.dispose();

        //Encode bitmap as file
        String mime = "image/png";
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        try {
            final BitmapEncoder encoder = BitmapEncoderRegistry.getInstance(mime);
            encoder.encode(bitmap, out, mime, dpi);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Command-line program.
     * @param args the command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SampleBarcodeEnhanced app = new SampleBarcodeEnhanced();
            File outputFile = new File("out.png");
            app.generate(outputFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar file using this link: 
//http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/java-barcode-generation.html#1

```
         /*            
          // Select a barcode type to create a Java barcode object 
          Code128 barcode = new Code128(); 

          // Set barcode data text to encode
          barcode.setData("Barcode-in-Java"); 

          // Set barcode data text to encode
          barcode.setX(2); 

          // Generate barcode & encode into GIF format
          barcode.drawBarcode("C://barcode-code128.gif"); 

          // Generate barcode & encode into JPEG format
          barcode.drawBarcode("C://barcode-code128.jpg"); 

          // Generate barcode & encode into EPS format
          barcode.drawBarcode2EPS("C://barcode-code128.eps"); 

          // Generate barcode & print into Graphics2D object
          barcode.drawBarcode("Java Graphics2D object"); 

          */
         String path=System.getProperty("user.home")   "/Desktop";
         String val = "val here"
         Code39 barcode = new Code39();
         barcode.setData(val);
         barcode.setX(2);
         barcode.drawBarcode(path "/" NIC ".png");
```